# Powershell script Get-WmiObject command not run from Task Scheduler

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, wmi, get-wmiobject

we have "**Access Denied**" error, when running the PS script from Task Scheduler, but it works fine when running directly from PS shell.
Even we are running command with localhost, we configured **DCOM** and **WMI** permissions similarly as in this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1140794/get-wmiobject-access-is-denied-(exception-from-hre)).
User was also granted "**Log on as a batch job**" permission via Local Security Policy.
Concern command:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -Filter "Name Like '%<service_name>%'"
```

Task scheduler is configured like below:

```
powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -windowstyle hidden -noninteractive -nologo -file "name_of_script.ps1"
```

Comment: Are they running with the same user?

Comment: yes, the same user

Comment: What is the exact error (PowerShell?) error? Where do you get the **"Access Denied"**  error? Is the script *"name_of_script.ps1"* on the local drive? Does the script run at all? (What happens when you add e.g. `WhoAmI | Out-File .\Test.txt` in the top?`)

Comment: How exactly did you create this scheduled task? Normally you need to supply the executable name (`powershell.exe`) and the commandline arguments (`-executionpolicy ...`) separately

Comment: **@Mathias R. Jessen**    
Program/Script: `%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`
Add Arguments: `-executionpolicy bypass -windowstyle hidden -noninteractive -nologo -File "D:\test\test.ps1"`

Comment: **@iRon**

Yes, the script is on drive D in the subfolder.
Yes, the other commands seems to work correctly, and the output is redirected to log file.

`Get-WmiObject : Access denied
At D:\test\test.ps1:27 char:2
+     Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -Filter "Name Like '%<service_name>%'" | S ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObject
   Command`

Comment: **Additional information:**
when the user is temporary added to **Administrators** group, the error is gone.
Unfortunately, this is not acceptable solution due to GPO.

Comment: I don't see why a regular user couldn't run that command, although the wildcard pattern doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I have no explanation, though pragmatically speaking the following _may_ help: switch to `Get-CimInstance` (which is preferable anyway, given that the WMI cmdlets are deprecated). Or, depending on what properties you need, try `Get-Service '*<service_name>*'` As an aside: you don't need `-nologo` in your CLI call; it is implied by `-File` (unless you also add `-NoExit`, which obviously doesn't make sense here).

Comment: @mklement0    get-ciminstance : Access denied 
At D:\test\test.ps1:29 char:2
+     get-ciminstance win32_service -filter "Name like '%<service_name>%'" | ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (:) [Get-CimInstance], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80041003,Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimCmdlets.Ge 
   tCimInstanceCommand

Comment: Looking at the definition of this error, it's not obvious how it relates to CIM/WMI: https://www.hresult.info/FACILITY_ITF/0x80041003 Does the `Get-Service` alternative work, at least in principle?

Comment: @mklement0 get-services works, but unfortunately do not show /run_as user on which services are running